# iReport Group results in different categories

Tags: jasper-reports, reporting, ireport

I have a dataset such as the following one:

```
Funder   Product    DueDate      Amount
=======================================
Fund1    Prod1      01/oct/2013  $1,500
Fund2    Prod1      01/oct/2013  $1,000
Fund3    Prod1      01/oct/2013  $850
Fund1    Prod2      01/oct/2013  $2,000
Fund2    Prod2      01/oct/2013  $750
Fund1    Prod1      02/oct/2013  $1,500
|        |          |            |
Fund3    Prod2      31/oct/2013  $750
```

That is, a lot of rows with amounts and duedates, with certain funder and product differentiating for similar duedates

What I need is to generate a report grouping by founder / product in such a way that all duedates for certain founder/product appear together, then for the next founder/product all the duedates belonging to them, etc.

Such as this:

```
Fund1
Prod1
DueDate     Amount
==================
01/oct/2013 $1,500
02/oct/2013 $1,500
03/oct/2013 $2,000
|           |
31/oct/2013 $1,750

Prod2
DueDate     Amount
==================
01/oct/2013 $2,000
02/oct/2013 $1,500
03/oct/2013 $2,000
|           |
31/oct/2013 $1,750


Fund2
Prod1
DueDate     Amount
==================
01/oct/2013 $1,000
02/oct/2013 $1,500
03/oct/2013 $2,000
|           |
31/oct/2013 $1,750

Prod2    
DueDate     Amount
==================
01/oct/2013 $750
02/oct/2013 $1,500
03/oct/2013 $2,000
|           |
31/oct/2013 $1,750


Fund3
Prod1    
DueDate     Amount
==================
01/oct/2013 $850
02/oct/2013 $1,500
03/oct/2013 $2,000
|           |
31/oct/2013 $1,750

Prod2
DueDate     Amount
==================
02/oct/2013 $1,500
03/oct/2013 $2,000
|           |
31/oct/2013 $750
```

By now, all I can get with iReport is to group by Founder / Group and repeating each group for different duedates, instead of grouping together all the duedates in each group. As this:

```
Fund1
Prod1

    DueDate     Amount
    ==================
    01/oct/2013 $850

Fund1
Prod2

    DueDate     Amount
    ==================
    01/oct/2013 $850

Fund2
Prod1

    DueDate     Amount
    ==================
    01/oct/2013 $850

Fund2
Prod2

    DueDate     Amount
    ==================
    01/oct/2013 $850

Fund3
Prod1

    DueDate     Amount
    ==================
    01/oct/2013 $850

Fund1
Prod1

    DueDate     Amount
    ==================
    02/oct/2013 $850

|
etc
```

Is there a way to achieve this?
Obviously, everything is just invented data, the behaviour is what I'm looking for...

Comment: Have you tried with two groups? First one grouping by Fund and second one grouping by Prod. I think you should be able to do it like this

Comment: Yes, I've tried with two groups. But it seems that grouping in iReport is just to display the details in several chunks, one detail for group and repeat and repeat, instead of really grouping details by the criteria defining the groups. I still wonder if there's a way to achieve it, it should...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've got it.

The problem was at my query, not at the report.

I was ordering everything by duedate on the SQL query and that made jasper to generate the result as I've showed.

Deleting that ordering criteria solved the problem.